# char配列から指定バイトだけ切り出したい(memcpyなど使わずに)

Tags: c++, c

この配列に何かバイナリデータが入っているとします。

```
char c[9]
```

これの先頭３バイトをintの変数に入れたいのですが、mem～系の関数を使わずに実現することは可能ですか？
ちなみに４バイト目以降は無傷で残しておきたいです。

【追記】
意味の分かりづらい質問ですいません。
このような感じです。エンディアンに関してはバイトオーダーの関数は後で使って調整できるものとします。なのでとにかくintに入れれば大丈夫です。

```
int n = 0;
char cc[4] = { 0xe8, 0x03, 0x00, 0x00 }; //数字の1000
memcpy(&n, cc, 3); // 3バイト取り出して1000を復元する
```

回答していただいた方々、ありがとうございます。
sanadanさんのコードをベースに下記の方法で数値を復元することができました。

```
char c[4] = {0x00,0x00,0x06,0x00};  // int6のネットワークバイトオーダー(3バイト目まで)
int x = (*(int *)c) & 0xffffff;  // この時点で0x00,0x06,0x00,0x00になる
x = x << 8;  // 3桁しか使わない
x = ntohl(x); // オーダー解決
```

yoh2さんの方法を使えばバイトオーダーも同時に解決できそうですね。

ご回答していただいた通り、このようなことをするよりも素直にmemcpyを利用しようかとも思っています。

【さらに追記】
よく考えたら任意の場所から取り出して最後の3バイトを取り出す場合もありそうなので、やはり上記コードは使えなさそうです。

最初の意図を明確にしておくと、
インプットデータはネットワークバイトオーダーのバイト配列でした。
それの3バイト目までをintとして扱いたいマシンはリトルエンディアンマシン。。でしたが、この質問を書き、回答を読んで将来ビッグエンディアンで使う可能性もあると思い直しました。
なので、ビットシフトなどは今回の用途では使わない方向でいきます。

Comment: 質問の意味がよくわかりません。`memcpy`を使用した場合のコードを提示してください。

Comment: 例えば、 `char c[4] = {0x11, 0x22, 0x33, 0x44}` の先頭から3バイトを取り出した時の結果はどんなものを期待していますか? その (1) `0x11223300` (ビッグエンディアンの4バイト整数、最後のバイトは0x44の代わりに0)、 (2) `0x00112233` (ビッグエンディアンの3バイト整数とみなす) (3) `0x00332211` (リトルエンディアンの4バイト、最後のバイトを0とみなす or リトルエンディアンの3バイト) (4) その他

Comment: そのコードを実行するアーキテクチャが決め打ちでいいのでなければ、 `char` 配列を直接 `int *` にキャストするのは止めた方がいいですよ。理由は sanadan さんの回答のコメントにもある通り、 `int` 境界にない場合が未定義のため。例外が発生してプログラムが止まる例や、何事もなかったかのように進むけど、実際は近くのint境界を始点として取って来た値になる例に遭遇したことがあります。

Comment: もうふたつ。まず、`ntohl()` を通す前にマスクやシフトを行うやり方では、ビッグエンディアンなアーキテクチャでは期待と異なる結果になります。次に、最終的に得られる値は、私の以前のコメントの (2) に当たるわけですが、それでいいのですか？

Comment: (2)で大丈夫です。
整数値としてあらわした際に、元のバイト配列の3バイト目が1桁目、１バイト目が3桁目になっていれば大丈夫です。

リトルエンディアンのマシン前提で考えていました。
たしかにシフトを行う前提でコードを書くのはまずいですね。
もう素直にmemcpyを使おうと思います。
ありがとうございました。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

一旦都合の良い形にコピーしてからntohlするのはいかがでしょうか。

```
char c[4] = {0x00,0x00,0x06,0x00};
char d[4] = {0x00};
memcpy(d + 1, c, 3);               // => {0x00,0x00,0x00,0x06}
x = ntohl(*(uint32_t *)d);         // => 6
```

すでに検討済みであったり、そもそもコピー先のメモリが惜しいという可能性がありますが、念のため投稿します。

Comment: はい、けっきょく自分もその結論に落ち着きました。
自分でバッファを用意してネットワークバイトオーダーの形にきちんと直してからコピーして、その後にntohl()を呼びます。
つまり示していただいたコードの通りです。
たぶんこれが一番安全で確実です。

Answer (score 6):

設計の都合上、後で必ずバイトオーダー変換関数を通さなければならない場合は h2so5 さんのコード。
その必要がなければ、最初から望みの値を得られるよう、以下のようにすればいいと思います。

```
/* CHAR_BIT = 8 と仮定してます */
char cc[] = ...;

int n = ((unsigned char)cc[0] <<  0) | ((unsigned char)cc[1] << 8) |
        ((unsigned char)cc[2] << 16);
```

3バイトのみのパターンだけではなく、`0` 〜 `sizeof(int)` バイトまでのパターンが有り得るならこんな感じで。

```
char cc[] = ...;
int m = ...; /* 先頭から何バイト取得したいか */

int n = 0;
for(size_t i = 0; i < m; i++)
{
    n |= (unsigned char)cc[i] << (i * 8)
}
```

[追記]
`0xe8, 0x03, 0x00, 0x00` の列から `1000` を取り出したいとのことでしたので、 `char` 配列に入っている値はリトルエンディアンであると思っていましたが、追記された

> `char c[4] = {0x00,0x00,0x06,0x00};  // int6のネットワークバイトオーダー(3バイト目まで)`

を見ると、ビッグエンディアン (= ネットワークバイトオーダー) のパターンもありそうです。
また、それ以降のコードからは `0x11, 0x22, 0x33, 0x44` からネットワークバイトオーダーで3バイトとは、 `0x11223300` (`0x11223344` の 下位1バイトをマスク) ではなく、 `0x00112233` (`0x112233` のみ取ってくる) を意図しているように見えます。
その場合ならこうですね。

バイト数が3固定:

```
/* CHAR_BIT = 8 と仮定してます */
char cc[] = ...;

int n = ((unsigned char)cc[0] << 16) | ((unsigned char)cc[1] << 8) |
        ((unsigned char)cc[2] <<  0);
```

バイト数が可変:

```
char cc[] = ...;
int m = ...; /* 先頭から何バイト取得したいか */

int n = 0;
for(size_t i = 0; i < m; i++)
{
    n |= (unsigned char)cc[i] << ((m - i - 1) * 8)
}
```

Answer (score 5):

memcpy()を避ける意義はなぜでしょう？
というのも今どきのコンパイラはmemcpy()の意味を知っていて直接インライン展開してしまいます。複雑な記述をするよりはmemcpy()でシンプルに記述した方がいいように思います。

Comment: memcpy(),strcpy()などは領域の重複時が未定義のためだと思います。最小限のメモリで予期しない動作を含まないプログラムを考えているのだと思います。

Comment: @natsukitinyak 今回の場合もそうですが別変数などソースレベルで重複しないことが明らかなパターンは多々あると思います。また重複を前提とするならばmemcpy()の代わりにmemmove()が用意されています。

Comment: 上はmemcpyでさじを投げていたので、コメントしました。それと、これは、質問が課題という雰囲気がありますので、質問の方に明日投票しますね。(サンプルを書いて正しく動かなかったら＋簡単に動いたら-という感じで、エンディアンまで触れられてると今更間違えることもないでしょうが。。。)；

Answer (score 3):

3バイト`memcpy`するのと同等のコードです。

```
int n = 0;
char cc[4] = { 0xe8, 0x03, 0x00, 0x00 };

char *p = (char*)&n;
p[0] = cc[0];
p[1] = cc[1];
p[2] = cc[2];
```

Answer (score 2):

```
int n = (*(int *)&c[i]) & 0xffffff;
```

で、任意のiの位置から3バイトをintで取得できますが、どうでしょう？

但し、最後の3バイトを取り出す場合があると、これはオーバーランしてしまって使えませんが。

Comment: `&c[i]` がint境界にないことがあるため未定義動作だと思います。

Answer (score 2):

面白そうな課題「mem～系の関数を使わずに文字列リテラルのビット列が示す整数値を表示せよ」として書いてみました。自己満足ですが何かのお役に立てればと思います。

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdint.h>
/*////////////////////////////////////////////////////
 * ミドルエンディアンまで対応する場合は
 * uint16_tを使って判定しリトルエンディアンと似た処理になるかと。
 * どこまで正常に動くかは未確認です。
 * ベストアンサーが決まったあとの回答を見てからの回答なのでちょっとせこいかもしれない
 * 質問の意図と大きく異っていたら申し訳ない
/*////////////////////////////////////////////////////

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    char c[]   = "Hello world!";
    int num[2] = {0}; // 
    int x = 1, i;

    //ここでバイト数が変更可能
    int isize = sizeof (int) / sizeof (char);

    int nsize = sizeof (num) / sizeof (num[0]);
    int csize = sizeof (c) / sizeof (c[0]);

    if (csize > nsize*isize) {
        if (*(char*) &x) {
            puts("little?");
            int j = csize;
            for (i = 0; i < nsize; i++)
                for (j = 0; j < isize; j++)
                    *(((unsigned char*) &num[i])+isize-j-1) = c[i*isize+j];
        } else {
            // これについてはデバッグできない。
            puts("big?");
            for (i = 0; i < nsize; i++) {
                num[i] = *(int*) &c[isize * i];
            }
        }

        for (i = 0; i < nsize; i++)printf("%d\n", num[i]);
        for (i = 0; i < csize; i++)printf("%c", c[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

純粋なコメントとして
/*////////////////////////////////////////////////////
 * チェックサムプログラムでエンディアンを気にしないとの記述を見たので調べたが
 * 全く関係がない内容だった。
 * こういったデータ構造まで気にしてプログラムを書くのは
 * 通信、OS、マイコン,ドライバ?関連のプログラマーだとおもう
 * (もしくは、コンパイラを作っているのかもしれない?)
 * いつもよりレベルが高くとても勉強になった。
/*////////////////////////////////////////////////////

Answer (score 0):

過去に似たような事をした人がPRJにいて奇々怪々なセグメンテーション違反が発生して2日間不具合に悩まされたことがありました。
ほかの方が書いているようにint境界にないと動作は未定義ですから`ntohl()`したうえでビットシフトとビットマスクすることがビッグエンディアン等プラットフォーム依存しないコードの記述だと思います。

Answer (score -5):

たぶんこれでいけると思います。

```
int i[3];
i[0] = c[0];
i[1] = c[1];
i[2] = c[2];
```